# A more serious version of 'no-holds-barred'

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

The phrase 'no-holds-barred' implies a fight, conflict or battle without any rules, but is relatively modern and comes from wrestling, giving it a friendly feel.

What is the name for a fight where one or more of the combatants will do anything to win? (not necessarily but including killing).

A prime example of this is when a character is trying to escape/kill the villain in a horror movie - nothing they do to fight back would be considered 'too far' (although in the movies they will usually panic instead of fighting with full force).

*Fight/brawl/punch-up* implies or belies some level of decorum (for example no biting, no eye-gouging, no false surrendering, no gratuitous use of 'unchivalrous' weapons).

*war/conflict/battle* implies some wider scope that may not be present.

Comment: "to the death"?

Comment: Neither fight nor brawl implies any level of decorum to my ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another phrase that's used to refer to an extremely violent fight is [*knock-down drag-out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock-down,%20drag-out).

> marked by extreme violence or bitterness and by the showing of no mercy

Answer (score 1):

The traditional term is

> [Fight to the finish / Fight to the
>   death](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-fight-to-the-death-finish)

a fight that continues until one side is completely defeated

When used to describe a serious contest the term "fight to the death" may be used figuratively in order to describe the inability of one party to respond to further attack. In such a case where mortality is not assured then Fight to the finish would be more apt / appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the OP's question, is, I am sorry to say:

***No Holds Barred***

The OP said that No Holds Barred is a modern term coming from wrestling, and thus has a friendly feel.  Wrestling does have rules, and no-holds-barred-wrestling is not at all friendly.  See [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/no-holds-barred.html) for just how unfriendly no-holds-barred wrestling can be.

From [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/no-holds-barred):

> If you say that there are no holds barred when people are fighting or
>   competing for something, you mean that they are no longer following
>   any rules in their efforts to win.
>
> It is a war with no holds barred and we must prepare to resist

Collins (same link) also says, for the British definition:

> all limitations removed

If we heard that a nuclear power was threatening a *no holds barred attack*, we would be justified in assuming that it had not ruled out nuclear.  Not friendly at all!

If the OP insists in escalating beyond *no holds barred*, I suggest repeating the phrase for emphasis:

> This is going to be no holds barred, ***and I mean no holds barred.***